# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API Social Login without Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build a web server with ASP.NET core as the back end and an SPA with vue.js as the front end. I'd like this server to be able to potentially serve ios, android, etc in the future. I would also like users to be able to sign in with their social log ins.

So far I've been working on Google log ins and have been following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) by Google. My front end authenticates to google fine and I am able to get the `id_token`. At this point I know that the token needs to be send to the back end for verification, but am not really sure how to do that or what to do next. I also don't know how the log in state of the site will be persisted. Will it use a cookie by Googlethat is validated with every request? A cookie by ASP.NET that is validated with every request? Something else all together? Basically, after authentication has taken place, how does every other API request to my server get validated?

After verifying the `id_token` does ASP.NET create a cookie to persist authentication and I can just follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1) by Microsoft? Or does some Google cookie get created and used for every request? If the latter, how would this work for providers other than Google?

I've also read [Google external login setup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1) by Microsoft and many other stack overflow posts but none seem to answer these questions thoroughly or at least I haven't found those answers.

A possible solution that I'm not sure is the best practice is to:

1. Authenticate the front end with Google like I am doing now
2. Send the `id_token` to the back end on some controller I create like /api/auth/google
3. Validate that token with something like `GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(Token);`
4. Create a ASP.NET cookie following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and use that cookie to persist authentication

Comment: I do this with my vue.....   in .net core you just authenticate with jwt tokens.   You simply have an api endpoint where you submit your id_token to and the backend verifies with google and issues the jwt token, then it's all jwt from that point on

Comment: @KeithNicholas So basically my proposed solution with the steps at the bottom, but with a JWT rather than a cookie? Are there any sort of best practices for this sort of thing? That seemed like a fairly intuitive approach to me, but I wasn't sure if there was some other way I was _supposed_ to do it.

Comment: yes and no ..... microsoft best practice is essentially the .net core identity stuff.   When it comes to SPAs they leverage identity server which lends itself to api only identity a lot better. I use this for various things, but is overkill for a simple webapp with a social login.   JWT seems to pretty popular ( if you notice googles tokens are jwt).  Somewhere I have demo code which is the minimal .net core code needed to do auth and to do auth using social.  I was going to blog about it.....it's on my todo :) Contact me via my profile if you want the code and I'll dig it up later.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'd love to see the demo code, especially if it is up to date, but even just letting my know that JWTs might be the way to go here for my simple little app has helped a ton and would be enough to put me on the right track.

Comment: @KeithNicholas do you have the demo code? If so, please share it

Comment: @jayasurya_j I have solved the answer to my question and can write up a solution if it would help you. It might be rough but my code currently works fine with google auth and custom jwt

Comment: that would be super helpful not just for me but for many folks!

Comment: @jayasurya_j oh boy, it's still on my todo list to write it up, if I get some time I'll try and at least commit all the different mini authentication combos into a github repo, I need to update then to .net 5 anyways.

Comment: @jayasurya_j I'll be sure to write something up tonight or tomorrow night. My solution was basically the suggested solution at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Montana Have you found the time to write something up? I'm running into the exact same issue here.